# Viewing monoid rings as rings with identity in GAP

Tags: monoid, gap, computer-algebra-systems

I look at monoid algebra of finite monoids with GAP and want to force GAP to view them as algebras with one. But it seems it does not work:

```
LoadPackage("smallsemi");
n:=6;
W:=AllSmallSemigroups(n,IsMonoidAsSemigroup,true);
U:=W[2];
T:=FreeMagmaRing(Rationals,U);
TT:=AsAlgebraWithOne(Rationals,T);
HasIdentity(TT);
```

$T$ is the the free magma ring of the finite monoid $U$ and GAP does not seem to know that it has an identity. So I use the command `AsAlgebraWithOne` to make GAP realise that this algebra has an identity but I still get the output "fail".

> Question: Is there an easy fix to make GAP view the algebra $T$ as an algebra with identity?

More generally, I want to use this command also to check whether a given finite semigroup algebra has an identity and then view the semigroup algebra as an algebra with identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually already `AsAlgebraWithOne` returns `fail` here. This is a fundamental misunderstanding about what this command does.

Anyway,  since your examples are tiny, one can simply achieve what you want by constructing an actual monoid (in the category of monoids, instead of the category of semigroups) as in this example.

Note that `HasIdentity` at first still returns `false`. This is because this function does not test whether an identity elements exists. Rather, it tests if a value for the `Identity` attribute of the algebra `T` exists (this attribute in turn is an alias for the `One` attribute). Thus after asking for `One(T)`, the return value of `HasOne` changes to `true` -- because the explicit request for `One(T)` computed an identity element, which was cached.

Here is the example code

```
gap> M:=MonoidByMultiplicationTable(MultiplicationTable(U));
<monoid of size 6, with 6 generators>
gap> T:=FreeMagmaRing(Rationals,M);
<algebra-with-one over Rationals, with 6 generators>
gap> IsAlgebraWithOne(T);
true
gap> HasIdentity(T);
false
gap> HasOne(T);
false
gap> One(T);
(1)*m6
gap> HasOne(T);
true
gap> HasIdentity(T);
true
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know a way that also will make GAP see the freemagma ring of a semigroup as an algebra with a one (if there is really a one)? Here a very strange example: n:=6;W:=AllSmallSemigroups(n);WW:=Filtered(W,x->IsMonoidAsSemigroup(x)=false); U:=WW[2];M:=SemigroupByMultiplicationTable(MultiplicationTable(U));T:=FreeMagmaRing(Rationals,M);

Comment: Using your tests for an identity dont work until I use HasOne(T); and obtain true for this example but it seems GAP doesnt want me to show the one as One(T); doesnt work despite GAP saying there is an identity.

Comment: Unclear what you mean: if you start with a monoid (as in my example) then `T` *is* an algebra-with-one (I just extended the example text to make that clear). I do not propose any "tests for an identity" either; `T` just has one.

Comment: The free magma ring of a semigroup that does *not* have an identity element is not an algebra-with-one, so I don't understand your first comment either...

Comment: A semigroup algebra can have a one even when the semigroup does not have an identity. For example look at the semigroups that define the incidence algebras of finite posets. They do not have an identity, but the semigroup algebra (=incidence algebra) has an identity.

Comment: Sorry, we are talking past each other: in GAP, whether something is a "monoid" or semigroup or group;   or a n "algebra" versus "algebra-with-one"; etc. depends on how it was created, and can't just be changed afterwards. It's like in category theory: the same "set with operation" can be a magma, semigroup, monoid, group (or even a ring, field, etc.).  An object in the category of semigroups is not an object in the category of monoids, *even if it happens to contain an element that behaves like a neutral element*.

Comment: Likewise if you create something as an algebra in GAP, it doesn't become an "algebra with one" just because you identify a neutral element.